# htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I am working in yii framework and try to rewrite url using htaccess file 
this is my file 
(at first step I am trying to work with a simple rule)

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^carguide$  MainModel/index/304 [NC,L]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php


# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I want to rewrite url carguide to mainModel/index/304, 
but no meter what i tried the yii receive the orliginal url and raise 404 error.

here is the log file:

```
strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/carguide -> carguide
applying pattern '^carguide$' to uri 'carguide'
RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/carguide' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/carguide' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite 'carguide' -> 'MainModel/index/304'
add per-dir prefix: MainModel/index/304 -> C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304
strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304 -> /cars/MainModel/index/304
internal redirect with /cars/MainModel/index/304 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel -> C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304
strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304 -> MainModel/index/304
applying pattern '^carguide1$' to uri 'MainModel/index/304'
add path info postfix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel -> C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304
strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel/index/304 -> MainModel/index/304
applying pattern '.' to uri 'MainModel/index/304'
RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/MainModel' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite 'MainModel/index/304' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php
strip document_root prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php -> /cars/index.php
internal redirect with /cars/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '^carguide$' to uri 'index.php'
strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php -> index.php
applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.php'
RewriteCond: input='C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/cars/index.php
```

I tried to change the flags, add a RewiteBase.

Comment: `internal redirect with /cars/MainModel/index/304 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]` This seems to be the issue and the Rewrite rules you've posted don't show anything that would cause this, so it's somewhere else in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you don't need to use `.htaccess` to create a particular rewrite rule for each page of your site. It's enough to use simple `.htaccess` as proposed [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config#apache) and then configure your rewrite rules using Yii's [URL manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url).

**UPDATE**

If your controller's name is `mainModel` and your action's name is `index` (in terms of Yii the route is `mainModel/index`) and you want this page to be accessable through `http://yoursite/carguide` then your configuration of URL manager in `protected/config/main.php` could look like this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        'carguide' => 'mainModel/index',
    )
),
```

**UPDATE**

Please refer to [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#properties) for configuration properties supported by Yii's URL manager class.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response,
i tried to add rule that will redirect this address.
the MainModel is my controller and the index is the action, but i got the 404 error:

Comment: What's the rule exactly you have added? I updated the answer with the example which works for me.

Comment: sorry, i submit the replay by mistake :) 
thanks alot it works - i add the right rule.